# Python scripts not working but Spyder and CMD

Tags: python, node.js, pandas

I am working with Anaconda-spyder, my scripts are working fine in spyder also I can run it from CMD
but I can not run my scripts with my Nodejs app

Nodejs

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");


router.get('/hi', (req, res, next)=> {
  console.log("here");

    PythonShell.run('pyt//home.py', {

        args: ['infoo']
      }, function (err, results) {   
        console.log("here2");
        if(results)
        { console.log(results);}
        if(err)
            { console.log(err);}
        });
      });

module.exports = router;
```

In python code, used libraries

```
import os
import sys
import tweepy,codecs
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import nltk
from textblob import Word
import six
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from os import path
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

import time
```

And getting the argv parameter in home.py with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    twt = sys.argv[1]   
    print("hi python")
```

When I run server, get the route with postman.  console says

```
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
      [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
      [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
      here
      here2
      { Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
          at PythonShell.parseError (C:\Users\username\Desktop\NodejsBitirme\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:258:21)
          at terminateIfNeeded (C:\Users\username\Desktop\NodejsBitirme\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:141:32)
          at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\Desktop\NodejsBitirme\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:133:13)
          at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
          at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
          ----- Python Traceback -----
          File "pyt\home.py", line 9, in <module>
```

Seems like installed libs problem. It work from cmd.

```
In the same folder
python home.py "hello"
```

It works

Comment: try adding   
import pip
 if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', "pandas"])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', "pandas"])

Comment: in the begining of the script

Comment: Hmm, but I think will give more erros for other libs

Comment: Because you don't have `pandas` in run session virtual environment

Comment: How can I add this libs to my virutal session

Comment: Any help ? I still can't

Comment: Check if there is a way to use a conda virtual env in node

Comment: Why is not working with simple way.It both uses CMD